# Unity for Android - object not following touch inputs

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch

I've just started learning Unity (using C#) and I'm trying to create script which will make object that script is attached to follow my touch inputs (basically follow my finger when I'm moving it around).

What I tried to do is:

EDIT: this is refreshed version what I have now.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {


    private Vector3 fingerEnd;

    void Start () {

    }

    void Update () {

        foreach(Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                fingerEnd = touch.position;
            }
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved && (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(fingerEnd.x,2) + Math.Pow(fingerEnd.y,2)) - Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(transform.position.x,2) + Math.Pow(transform.position.y,2))<100))
            {
                fingerEnd = touch.position;
                Vector3 worldCoordinates = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(fingerEnd);
                transform.Translate(worldCoordinates);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I've also tried using `Vector2.Lerp`, but still my object isn't moving. It's probably very basic mistake but I don't see what's not working here.

I also tried to change

```
fingerEnd = touch.position;
Vector3 worldCoordinates = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(fingerEnd);
transform.Translate(worldCoordinates);
```

to

```
fingerEnd = touch.position;
transform.Translate(fingerEnd);
```

or to

```
fingerEnd = touch.position;
Vector3 worldCoordinates = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(fingerEnd);
transform.position = worldCoordinates;
```

or to

```
fingerEnd = touch.position;
transform.position = fingerEnd ;
```

with no effect.

EDIT: Ok, I've solved it. It was my mistake. In IF clause I've used touch.position (fingerEnd) values, before I knew this is position in pixels on screen. I compared it to transform.position which was in unity coordinates. It worked when I separated these 2 conditions from IF.

End version of code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 worldCoordinates;

    void Start () {

    }

    void Update () {

        foreach(Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                Debug.Log("Touch: " + touch.position);
            }
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) 
            {
                worldCoordinates = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);

                if ((Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(worldCoordinates.x,2) + Math.Pow(worldCoordinates.y,2)) - Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(transform.position.x,2) + Math.Pow(transform.position.y,2))<0.2))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Touch: " + touch.position);
                    Debug.Log("Transform: " + transform.position);
                    Debug.Log("WorldCoordinates: " + worldCoordinates);
                    //transform.Translate(worldCoordinates);
                    transform.position = new Vector3(worldCoordinates.x,worldCoordinates.y);
                    //transform.Translate(touch.position);
                    Debug.Log("Transform 2: " + transform.position);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Object now follows my finger. It's kinda slow (staying behind all the time unless I stop) but it's another problem to solve. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [touch.position](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-position.html) The position of the touch in pixel coordinates.

So first of all, you need to convert position to world (unity world) coordinates.

You should use the [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) to your code(Maybe main camera).

For example:

```
Vector3 worldCoordinates = yourCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(fingerEnd);
transform.Translate(worldCoordinates);
```

Comment: I feel it's the right direction, but I have a problem with a camera. I've also tried to set new parameter (private Camera mainCamera;), and initialized it with "mainCamera = GetComponent<Camera>()". Then I use two line syou have given (with mainCamera instead of yourCamera of course).

Still, nothing works. I assume, instead of new Camera parameter I should use the one that was already in the project from the very beginning, but I'm not sure how (tried to use gameobject.getobjectwithtag, but it didn't work).

Comment: Did you try Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint ?

Comment: I've tried it now, but it seems the problem remains the same with or without ScreenToWorlPoint. My object starts in the middle of the screen, but it reacts when I swipe my finer on the top of the screen (from upper left o upper right). It also doesn't follow my touch, and just moves very fast (I lose sight of it immediately) in the upper left corner direction. I clearly do somemething wrong with coordinates.

I uise phone in the landscape position.
I've added updated code to the main post.

Comment: If i understand you truely, maybe you set position directly not translate. (this.transform.position= worldCoordinates; this sets position directly. Please try it.

Comment: Ok, solved it. I explained it in the main post if anybody will need it (which I doubt ;] ).

Answer (score 1):

you need to change

```
transform.position = fingerEnd;
```

to

```
transform.Translate(fingerEnd);
```

Comment: That's partially good, my object started reacting to something, but not in the way I wanted it to. After one specific move it moves to far far away coordinates (like x = 6000+ and y = 4000+ for instance). I assume it has something to do with ScreenToWorldPoint mentioned in the other answer